# How can I get plain text message body using imap and Java code?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

I am developing such an app that sends email properly.
but during fetching emails i am getting html coded message body.. But i want message body as it is in plain text type.
So please direct me.

My code for receiving email  is that:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;



public class InboxReader {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            try {
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
                store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "emailId@gmail.com", "password");
                System.out.println(store);

                Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
                inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);



                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                        // Get directory

                        Message message[] = inbox.getMessages();


                        //Message message[] = folder.getMessages();
                        for (int i=0, n=message.length; i<n; i++) 
                        {
                        System.out.println(i + ": " + message[i].getFrom()[0]
                        + "\t" + message[i].getSubject());

                        System.out.println("Do you want to read message? " +
                        "[YES to read/QUIT to end]");
                        String line = reader.readLine();
                        if ("YES".equals(line)) {
                        message[i].writeTo(System.out);
                        } else if ("QUIT".equals(line)) {
                        break;
                        }
                        }
                        }
         catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends upon the sender, you will receive whatever he sends. As Bill suggested look for different type of `MimeTypes` you get in the message body.
However, if you're sure you will receive `HTML`, you can convert it to `plain text` easily using the JSoup library. And if not sure, you would first have to extract HTML from the MultiPart objects and then convert it to Plain Text.

Example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HTMLText);

String plainText = doc.body().text();

System.out.println(plainText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get what the sender sent you.  If they only sent you html, you only get html.  In many cases they will send you a multipart/alternative message that contains the same content in both plain text and html versions.  This [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody) will get you started.

But, it the message only contains html content and you want plain text, you're going to have to process the html content yourself and try to convert it to plain text.  Depending on how good a job you want to do, this is either relatively easy, or very very hard.